# Having trouble adding an .active state style to a nav bar although a:hover is OK

Tags: jquery, css

As you can see from the image the active state (link 1) used in some jQuery to change an element to "active" has styling issues. I'd like it to look like the a:hover state shown at link three.

Here are the links:

[nav bar image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dfbyU.png)

All my efforts to have it (the .active state css) look like the a:hover state have failed. Does anyone have any ideas how I can make the.active state text line up with the other links?

Links html:

```
<div class="col-12">
              <div class="resources-links make-active" id="resources-nav">
                        <a id="tab1" class="tab active">link 1</a>
                        <a id="tab2" class="tab">link 2</a>
                        <a id="tab3" class="tab">link 3</a>
                        <a id="tab4" class="tab">link 4</a>
                        <a id="tab5" class="tab">link 5</a>
                        <a id="tab6" class="tab">link 6</a>
                        <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">
                        <i id="resources-nav-chevron" class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i>
                      </a>
                </div>
             </div>
```

CSS:

```
.use-case-nav-bk {    
    background-color: #F9FAFA;
}
/*
#use-cases-nav .resources-nav {
    height: 71px;
}
*/    

#use-cases-nav .resources-links {
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #F9FAFA;
    width: 96%;
    padding-left: 40px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#use-cases-nav .resources-links a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #9b9999;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 28px 18px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: Gilroy-Extrabold, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
}

#use-cases-nav .resources-links a:hover {
    background-color: #B5B5B5;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 42px;
    margin-top:20px;
}

.resources-links .active  {   
    color: #2359B9 !important;
    background-color: #B5B5B5;    
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 42px;
    margin-top:20px;
}

#use-cases-nav .resources-links .icon {
    display: none;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.make-active a').click(function(event){
        $('.active').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

JSFIddle: https://jsfiddle.net/webbtrad/ek93L5rn/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is specificity of the selector for the `.active` class

You're using

```css
.resources-links .active
```

But are targeting all the `a` tags with

```css
#use-cases-nav .resources-links a
```

Which has higher specificity because of that leading `#use-cases-nav` - so the `padding` properties you're tying to override aren't being overridden.

The padding property *is* being overridden for the `a:hover` selector though, because it does have higher specificity.

```css
#use-cases-nav .resources-links a:hover
```

That's why the two don't match, despite having identical CSS.

Your solution is simple, just drop a `#use-cases-nav` into your `.active` selector:

```css
#use-cases-nav .resources-links .active
```